# How to get Elastic Container Repository URI from Cloud Formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create an Elastic Container Service (ECS) setup from Cloud Formation.

However I don't want the ECS repository to have the ugly autogenerated URI:

**111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docker-repo.company.com**

but instead I want it to have a nice and shiny

**docker-repo.company.com**

The repository itself does not allow setting the URI or [even a CNAME](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223934). So I'm trying to setup a S3 bucket to redirect to the repo. However unless I'm missing something, Cloud Formation doesn't support this since using !Ref or !GetAtt there's nothing I can query in the AWS::ECR::Repository object that will give me the repository URI.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just run a [registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/)? They're pretty [simple to setup](https://docs.docker.com/registry/)

Comment: True, but what would be the point if we plan on using ECS anyway? This way AWS manages it for us, we minimize the number of services we have to manage ourselves.

Comment: Yeah, only if the requirements that fall outside the specific setup of an ECR are worth it to you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is kind of silly, but in the end it seems you cannot refer to the URI of an ECR because Cloud Formation doesn't support it.

There's [no attribute for the URI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecr-repository.html), even though funnily enough their [Ruby SDK does support it](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ECR/Types/Repository.html) and even the [third-party, cross-cloud Terraform supports it](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ecr_repository.html).

However, you can hack around this because the repository URI is stable, it doesn't contain any random part, so you can compose the URI from things you already have:

```
HostName: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${dockerrepocompanycom}"
```

or for the less cool, old-school version:

```
HostName: !Join [ ".", [ !Ref "AWS::AccountId", "dkr.ecr", !Ref "AWS::Region", !Join [ "/", [ "amazonaws.com", !Ref "dockerrepocompanycom" ] ] ] ]
```

Full working configuration for creating the S3 bucket:

```
   s3dockerrepo1redirect:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
        BucketName: "docker-repo.company.com"
        WebsiteConfiguration:
            RedirectAllRequestsTo:
               HostName: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${dockerrepocompanycom}"
```

Comment: You know what's even more disappointing? Having to use a globally distributed infrastructure (Cloud Front) for any kind of setup involving custom domain names and HTTPS, on AWS. Unless I missed something :( I say this because the S3 setup didn't work in the end for our requirements and I had to resort to Cloud Front.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> HostName: !Join [ ".", [ !Ref "AWS::AccountId", "dkr.ecr", !Ref "AWS::Region", !Join [ "/", [ "amazonaws.com", !Ref "dockerrepocompanycom" ] ] ] ]
> ```

A more concise way is as follows:

```
HostName: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${dockerrepocompanycom}"
```

(adding as separate answer because I lack reputation points to comment on previous answer)

Comment: If it's ok with you I'll edit my answer to include your improved version.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, @sgeb!